# How to fix MongoDB saving object under array and 0: "[object Object]"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am trying to save a settings object in a document but it won't save right.

Schema:

```
const guild = mongoose.Schema({
guildName: String,
guildId: String,
guildSettings: {type: [Object], blackbox: true },
guildBlacklists: Object,
});
```

Object trying to be saved:

```
{
  minimumMembers: '4',
  serverType: 'roblox',
  allowOutsideServers: 'true'
}
```

Save code:

```
await guildSchema.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
            guildId: interaction.guild.id,
        },
        {
guildName: interaction.guild.name,
guildId: interaction.guild.id,
guildSettings: `${settings}`,
guildBlacklists: null,

    

        },
        {
            upsert: true,
        }
    );
```

Instead of saving the object it saves as:

```
guildSettings: Array
     0: "[object Object]"
```

Comment: Can you provide an example JSON object that you are trying to save?

Comment: Maybe this will help? `guildSettings: [{type: Object, blackbox: true }],`

Comment: Can you post the code where you try to save the document?

Comment: await guildSchema.findOneAndUpdate(
   {
    guildId: interaction.guild.id,
   },
   {
guildName: interaction.guild.name,
guildId: interaction.guild.id,
guildSettings: `${settings}`,
guildBlacklists: null,
        

   },
   {
    upsert: true,
   }
  );

Object:

{
  minimumMembers: '4',
  serverType: 'roblox',
  allowOutsideServers: 'true'
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. It was because I used `${}` which made it a string.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it solved the problem.